# Different React-Native versions giving different android apk sizes

Tags: android, apk, react-native

I have worked with few of the versions of [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/), `0.57.7`,`0.59.3`,`0.59.9` and all of them generate different size apk for default app generated by [react-native-cli](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started#the-react-native-cli-1).

approx sizes are

`0.57.7 : 12mb`,
`0.59.3 : 28mb`,
`0.59.9 : 15mb`

My question is, How is this happening and which is the best version to use that gives least apk size?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to keep your react native version updated to the latest stable build,

Because once you're behind 3 or 4 versions then upgrading to latest becomes more complicated.

And for your concern of app size,

React-Native uses its own core libs, plus you may have used some other libs,
target SDK versions(26,27,28...), app-compat libs versions,play services...  these are some of the Highlighted things that could increase
your app size.

If you want to decrease you app size,

you can split it per architecture like "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a" and "arm64-v8a"

[How to split React-Native apk per architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56033583/8820972)

this could strongly reduce 65%+ of your app size.