# How to build a 64bit version for Android in React Native without upgrade to 0.59.x?

Tags: react-native, google-play, 64-bit

Now I have 10 projects using React Native, but its version is only 0.53.3

As I know, React Native team has supported building 64 bit for Android in 0.59.x, but I don't have enough time to upgrade all of my projects to this version. In addition, 0.53.3 to 0.59.x is the long time, it will take so much effort to upgrade. My projects also have many third party libs, I dont want to check all of them.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56033583/4493604), but after I built the release apk then install it to Android devices, the app crashed.

Anyone solve this problem without upgrade app to 0.59.x? Many thanks!